# Webconfig redirecting from www.example.com to http://example.com

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6

Im trying to redirect my website from www.example.com to example.com with the following code but i get 500 error.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect from WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Would you please let me know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Is your DNS server setup to resolve example.com, without the www???

that might be your issue

Comment: Paulo, Its not possible because if somebody type www before address will get error. I want if somebody typed www redirect to http:// automatically.

Comment: I know. but I was thinking that, if you have both WWW.site and site pointing to the same location you wouldn't get that error. Or you could setup a new website, on the IIS, with www,  pointing to the site without. when you create the website, on the IIS, right click, propeties and select the tab "home directory", you have the option to redirect to a URL.

just a tought, hope that helps

cheers